# Road Miles Calculation without Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps, distance

We have two ZIP codes we want to calculate the road mile difference.

Google maps states you cannot use their API if you do not show a map. Is there another service that provides this type of calculation? I have searched Google but nothing has turned up useful.

Currently we use lat/lon to get as the crow flies calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) project have some links to routing software which covers totally or partially the maps.

Here is the link to their wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers

and here is one of the open API: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open

After this, the first provided link can give you some other links where the routing is only online, but some others can provide an open API. But some more research still have to be made...

Good luck.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.